# vim substitution with mathematical expression

Tags: vim, substitution

I need to replace following line:

```
[rescap] l=1.2u w=1.5u
```

by

```
[rescap] l=1.2u w=1.5u r=0.8k
```

value of r 0.8k is l/w

I am trying in vim (already done in perl but wanted to implement using vim)

```
:s/l=\\(.\*\\)u w=\\(.\*\\)u/l=\1u w=\2u r=\1*\2k/
```

but it does not evaluate expression and prints:

> [rescap] l=1.2u w=1.5u r=1.2*1.5k

If I try \= which evaluates expression it assumes l and w as variable and throws out error.

```
:s/l=\\(.\*\\)u w=\\(.\*\\)u/\=l=\1u w=\2u r=\1*\2/
```

I have to run above expression using vim -s scriptfile through many files.
just need to figure out the above substitution statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for:

```
%s#\vl\=([0-9.]+)u\s+w\=([0-9.]+)u\zs.*#\=' r='.string(eval(submatch(1))/eval(submatch(2))).'u'
```

The important things are:

- `\=` that tells you'll be inserting an expression -- the 3rd one (the first two are quirks induced by my use of very-magic regex with `\v`) -> `:h :s\=`
- `submatch()` to access `\1` and `\2`
- `eval()` to convert the submatches into floating point numbers, and `string()` to convert it back
- also note that in order to insert text after `\=`, you need to explicitly build a string

Then, I've used:

- `\v` to simplify the regex,
- `:s#` instead of `:s/` to simplify the *replacement* expression as I need `/` to compute a division,
- `\zs` to simplify the *replacement* expression as well.

Last need to know piece of information, to reach the documentation related to regex/pattern, prepend what you are looking for with a slash -> `:h /\v`, `:h /\zs`

Comment: Thanks Luc . Exactly the way i wanted. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user2508758 pls accept the answer if it really solved your problem. That's the way you say "thank" at SO

Answer (score 2):

The following command will also work:

```
s#\vl\=(\d+\.\d+)u w\=(\d+\.\d+)u#\=printf('%s r=%.1fk', submatch(0), str2float(submatch(1))/str2float(submatch(2)))
```

Some explanation:

- `submatch(0)` will contain all the matched string
- `str2float()` is used to convert string to float type
- `printf()` is to used for ease of control of output string format.

Comment: Nice simplification with `printf()`. Note: there is a little limitation in this solution: it won't accept integers -- while my regex accepts incorrect numbers like `1.1.2`.